# Is there a way to get the package or directory/location of a running node?

Tags: ros, node, rosnode, rospack, rosmaster

Is there a way to get the package name or directory/location of a running node? Preferably from within a separate python node.

Things I've tried:

- `rosnode info` doesn't seem to give any info on which package the node is running in.
- `rosgraph.masterapi.Master.lookupNode() will give me the IP address, but no package information.
- I could search for nodes manually using a linux command like `locate` or `find` for the name, but if there are multiple packages that have the same node name, I won't know which is actually running.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the package at runtime? I don't know the answer to your question, but maybe there is an alternative for what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Another issue I'll point out is that since ros is a distributed system, the ros package may not even be installed locally on the machine this hypothetical python code is executing on.